# What are the dangers of not closing files in Python?

Tags: python, file

What could happen if I open a file but forget to use `close()` on it in Python?

My old programming teacher told me that is bad practice NOT to close files after using `open()` on them. He mentioned that the reference goes to 0.

Why is closing files important in Python?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this. Maybe ask yourself, what happens if you have an important word document, but you don't close it?

Comment: Do not know but still better be safe then sorry

Comment: Check out this https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-January/088031.html